# How to install python-igraph on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS 64-Bit?

Tags: python, 64-bit, ubuntu-8.04, igraph

Apparently `libigraph` and `python-igraph` are the only packages on earth that can't be installed via `apt-get` or `easy_install` under Ubuntu 8.04 LTS 64-bit.

Installing both from source from source on seems to go smoothly...until I try to use them.

When I run python I get:

```
>>> import igraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "igraph/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from igraph.core import *
 ImportError: No module named core
```

or (if I use the easy_install version of python-igraph)

```
>>> import igraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/igraph/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/igraph/core.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/igraph/core.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: libigraph.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I grabbed the source from here

igraph 0.5.2 = http://igraph.sourceforge.net/download.html

python-igraph 0.5.2 = http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-igraph/0.5.2

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How did you compile? Did you do a make install (if there was any).

As for the 'library not found' error in the easy_install version, i'd try the following:

1. '`sudo updatedb`' (to update the locate database)
2. '`locate libigraph.so.0`' (to find where this file is on your system. If you did a make install it could have went to /usr/local/lib ... or is it in the python lib dir?)
3. Find out if the directory where this file is in is missing from your current LD_LIBRARY_PATH ('`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`').
4. If this directory is not in here, add it try '`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/yourdirhere`' (make it permanent by adding it to /etc/ld.so.conf) / '`ldconfig -n /yourdirhere`'

Comment: libigraph.so was indeed in /usr/local/lib.  I figured that was a pretty common location for libraries though, I guess python doesn't look there?.

You steps fixed it in 2 secs, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are official Ubuntu packages for igraph available from Launchpad as of 8 Nov 2009. See the corresponding [page](https://launchpad.net/~igraph/+archive/ppa) on Launchpad for instructions. Unlike the earlier Debian package repository, this should work on both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Where is libigraph.so.0 ? It doesn't seem to be in a location that python looks for such as /usr/lib , /usr/local/lib etc.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in http://socialsynergyweb.org/network/blog/install-python-igraph-ubuntu-904-64-bit. Also to run the actual igraph , i used the script python-igraph-0.5.2/scripts/igraph. Now i am able to use the igraph . If I dont use the scripts/igraph script i get the same error you are getting.

Comment: Link is dead, user is inactive, all is lost.